# iterate over all files in directory

Tags: bash, glob

I'm trying to write a BASH script that iterate over all files in directory and if the file is not `zip` than zip it

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start"
for f in *
do
        echo "Start loop $f "
        # if .bak backup file exists, read next file
    if [ -${f} = *.zip ]
    then
        echo "Skiping $f file..."
        continue  # read next file and skip the cp command
    fi
        zip $f.zip $f
done
echo "Closing"
```

I have the following files in the directory: `1, 2, 3.zip, zipper.sh`
the output of the script over the directory needs to be

```
1, 1.zip, 2, 2.zip, 3.zip, zipper.sh, zipper.sh.zip
```

but it also creating `3.zip.zip`

Comment: I don't think `if [ -${f} = *.zip ]` does what you think it does.

Comment: Take a look at this output: `shopt -s extglob; for f in !(*.zip); do echo "$f"; done`

Comment: @Cyrus I see the output for your command, but I don't understand how to implement it in my script.

Comment: @yaodav Read the bash manual and look for a topic about extended globs or patterns. You'll also have to consider zip files that already exist that maybe you would want or wouldn't want to override them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this below code.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in `find . -type f -not -name "*.zip"`;
do
  #echo $f
  zip "$f".zip  $f
done
```

Comment: What if the file names contain spaces?